# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property "value" of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-cli

I am using Angular 7 and trying to fix one of the issue in IE 11. My app usually is working but sometimes is not loading correctly, especially when I refresh cache (ctrl + f5). I included all pollyfils for IE in my project:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

But sometimes page is not loading and this error appear in console:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property "value" of undefined or null
>   reference

The error is linked to this part of code in pollyfills.js:

```
try {
     if (task.type == macroTask && task.data && !task.data.isPeriodic){
         task.cancelFn = undefined;
     }
     try{
         return this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, applyThis, applyArgs);
     }
     catch(error){
         if(this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)){
             throw error;
         }
     }
}
```

I missed some polyfills for zone.js?

Comment: You can try to check which document mode you are using in IE 11. Default mode is IE 7. You can change it to the latest one. Also try to add this line in your code. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> for testing purpose, try to uncomment import 'classlist.js';  Let us know, whether it helps or not.

Comment: I am using IE 11 in document mode and I imported 'classlist.js'; already. I added this meta tag which you mentioned but I still have same error.

Comment: I again checked and find that generally it is caused when HTML element is not found, and if we want to get the value, it will show this error. So, I think the issue is not related to the code in the Polyfills, it is better to check which line show this error. I also suggest you to install Zone.js and add this polyfil import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js?activeTab=readme

Comment: I imported zone.js already, it's required by default for Angular itself.

Comment: Please try to debug the code. check and verify that all the objects are set properly and parameters has correct values in it in this line. this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, applyThis, applyArgs) If one of the parameter does not have an proper value than it can cause this error.